# How to change the text color by a function in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

How does one achieve the following:

If (the value of cell A1) < (than the value 0) then (all the text representing the number in cell A1) should be the color (RED)?

Comment: You don't need comditional formatting to do this.  Right click on the cell and select formatting.  Select "Number" from the listbox and then select one of the two options with red in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic conditional formatting will do this (without adding a function directly inside the cell)

1. Select your cell/ cell range from top left down (I used `A1:A3` below)
2. From the *Home* tab on the ribbon , pick *Conditional Formatting*
3. Pick "Format only cells that contain"
4. `Cell Value ....  less than  ..... =0`
5. click Format and pick a Red font

Debra Dalgleish has an excellent reference on conditional formatting [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlcondformat01.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, so I'm going to make a few assumptions in trying to understand and answer it. Maybe your instructor had the same problem?

In writing VBA code, you can get/set the text color of a cell by accessing the `ColorIndex` property. This value represents the index of one of the default color values, between 1 and 56. And in addition to the 56 colors already in the palette, there are two special values: `xlColorIndexNone` specifies that no color has been assigned, and `xlColorIndexAutomatic` specifies that the default color is used.

For example, to set the text color of cell (1, 3) to red, you would write:

```
Cell(1, 3).Font.ColorIndex = 3
```

Comment: You overthink this.By the way my insturctor under stay the qusetion just fine this is not vba code. What I am talking about is Microsoft excel 2010 nothing more.